# Are Rack-Servers always loud?

Tags: rack, blade-server

So,
I'm thinking about getting a rack server (one blade) at home for stuff like gameserver, rendering, webserver, cloud etc but I'm worried about the loudness of the fans. 
I've only seen one single server rack in real life and it was pretty loud (and warm) so I'm unsure if every server is really that loud or if there can be pretty quite ones (if they are idle and not working).

Would it be possible to have a rack server that is as loud as a gaming pc tower?

And please don't give me replies like "If you dont know that, then you don't need a server." I'm a web dev but would like to learn about how to setup hardware aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, these are always loud.
Fans may go slower if the temperature's cold enough. Even though, you'll always ear it. Even with a couple closed doors in the way, ...

In addition to the noise, you should also consider these are hotter. And if you don't have some sort of air conditioner, fans would run faster, ...

The main advantage of rack servers, I would say, is that it takes less space.
You'll find tower servers (HP DLs, Dell PE-T series, ...) with dual CPUs, dual PSUs, hot-swap-able drives, enterprise-grade raid chipsets, KVM-over-IP, SAS capabilities, ... same as a rack server. Yet way more discrete in terms of noise. And from 4 to 6x bigger.

Comment: The fans in a rack server are much louder because they must be much smaller and run at much higher RPM to fit in the available space and still deliver enough airflow. This is generally not something you want at home.